# SQL Server - DateTime Conversion field Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Got following fields in table:

Run Date  : 2011-09-25 00:00:00.000

Run Time : 05:00:00

Run Duration :  03:22:51

What I need is in Dateformat

Run Date + Run Time = Start Time of Job (DateTime Format)

Run Date + (Run Time + Run Duration) = End Time of Job (DateTime Format)

I'm struggling to do conversion. Can anyone please help.

This is the STORED PROCEDURE which I'm using - can anyone advise how to monitor this:

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_listjobrunhistory] @dateparam DATETIME,
                                              @JobName   VARCHAR(100)
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT --sysjobhistory.server,
             sysjobs.name
             AS
             job_name,
             CASE sysjobhistory.run_status
               WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
               WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
               ELSE '???'
             END
             AS
             run_status,
             CAST(
             Isnull(Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_date), 1, 4) + '-' +
                           Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR
                                     (8), run_date), 5, 2) + '-' +
                    Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(
                              8), run_date), 7, 2), '') AS DATETIME)
             AS
             [Run DATE],

```
         Isnull(Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), run_time+1000000), 2, 2) + ':'
                 +
                       Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), run_time+1000000), 4, 2
                        )
                +
                ':' +
                Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), run_time+1000000), 6, 2), '') 
         AS
         [Run TIME],
         Isnull(Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), run_duration+1000000), 2, 2) +
                 ':' +
                       Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), run_duration+1000000),
                       4,
                       2)
                + ':' +
                Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), run_duration+1000000), 6, 2),
         ''
         ) AS
         [Duration],
         Isnull(Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), run_time+run_duration+1000000), 2, 2) + ':'
                 +
                       Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), run_time+run_duration+1000000), 4, 2
                        )
                +
                ':' +
                Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), run_time+run_duration+1000000), 6, 2), '')
         AS
         [Total TIME],             
         sysjobhistory.step_id,
         sysjobhistory.step_name,
         sysjobhistory.MESSAGE
  FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
         INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs
           ON msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id
  WHERE  sysjobhistory.run_date <= Datepart(yyyy, @dateparam) * 10000 +
                                         Datepart(mm, @dateparam) * 100 +
                                  Datepart
                                  (
                                         dd, @dateparam)
         AND sysjobs.name = @JobName --remove this line if you want to show all jobs for the specified day
  ORDER  BY instance_id DESC
```

END
Regards

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson good call, I should have asked that before answering.  I assumed a minimum of SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, no conversion is required.

```
declare @T table
(
  RunDate datetime,
  RunTime time,
  RunDuration time
)

insert into @T values('2011-09-25 00:00:00.000', '05:00:00', '03:22:51')

select RunDate + RunTime as StartTimeOfJob,
       RunDate + RunTime + RunDuration as EndTimeOfJob
from @T
```

And in versions before 2008 it could be like this.

```
declare @T table
(
  RunDate datetime,
  RunTime varchar(8),
  RunDuration varchar(8)
)

insert into @T values(
'2011-09-25 00:00:00.000',
'05:00:00',
'03:22:51')

select RunDate + RunTime as StartTimeOfJob,
       RunDate + RunTime + RunDuration as EndTimeOfJob
from @T
```

Ooops. No conversions needed there either.

Comment: @jmoreno - It **could** be a date but not when the value is specified as it is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to accomplish what you are looking for:

```
create table dbo.RunDurationTest
(
    RunDate datetime not null,
    RunTime time not null,
    RunDuration time not null
)

insert into rundurationtest
values ('2011-09-25 00:00:00.000', '05:00:00', '03:22:51')

select 
    (RunDate + RunTime) as RunDateTime,
    (RunDate + RunTime + RunDuration) as EndRunDateTime,
    *
from rundurationtest
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `[Run Time]` and `[Run Duration]` are `varchar` fields, I'd have the following:

```
select StartJob = [Run Date] + convert(datetime, [Run Time])

select EndJob   = StartJob + convert(datetime, [Run Duration])
```